# Very thin, flexible wire for LEDs -> Arduino inside cramped space?

Tags: arduino

I'd like to fit an Arduino inside of a metal broomstick, and use it to drive groupings of LEDs that poke out of the stick. It's a light toy. The Arduino fits, so do the AA's, but I need wire that's flexible enough to work in tight spaces, and that I can solder to both the Arduino and LEDs. Once it's all packaged inside, it shouldn't have to flex at all.

Can anyone recommend wire for this?

Comment: As Olin said - wire wrap wire is potentially useful - strong for its size but able to be broken if enough care is not taken. Look for Kynar or Tefzel covered wire. These are almost soldering iron proof and will not creep back along the wires under heavy soldering iron abuse. . Also VERY hard to strip well.

Answer (score 1):

There are all kinds of wire.  Maybe for your case "wire wrap" wire is applicable since it's available and cheap.  This is usually quite thin, like 30 guage.  Of course wire this thin isn't too robust.  If you're sure you only need to flex it a few times and then it's fixed in place, wire wrap wire might do it.

I think you're going to be fiddling with this thing more than you realize.  Wire wrap wire, or any single-strand wire, will break after enough flexes.  Is the wire size really that big a deal?  Of course 14 gauge house wiring would be silly, but it's hard to imagine ordinary stranded 24 guage hookup wire being big enough to be a problem.  You may want to get some with relatively low insulation voltage so that the insulation will be smaller in diameter.